# matrix multiplication using numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have two matrices

```
a = matrix(((1.4) ,(2.5) ,(1.96),(6.25),(12.25))
```

and

```
b = matrix(((1 ,1,1,1,1),(2,2,2,2,2)))
```

when i multiply these matrices

```
product = b*a
```

i am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy-1.7.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 330, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

please help me to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrices are the wrong shape to multiply them.  I think you probably meant to define `a` as:

```
a = matrix(((1.4,),(2.5,),(1.96,),(6.25,),(12.25,)))
```

which is the same thing as:

```
a = matrix((1.4,2.5,1.96,6.25,12.25)).T
```

or

```
a = matrix(((1.4),(2.5),(1.96),(6.25),(12.25))).T
```

Please note that the **comma** is what makes a tuple.  The parenthesis are only to avoid ambiguity in the syntax.  In the last example, the inner-most groups of parenthesis do nothing and are removed by python's parser.